# Yeoman generator using slim templates

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, slim, bower

I've been trying to write my own generator based on the default webapp but it is very confusing and the documentation is pretty terrible in explaining the process for beginners. What I'm trying to get is to be able to write slim templates and have the generator convert them to hmtl. I tried doing that with the grunt-slim package but got nowhere so far. If anyone has any hits, that'd be appreciated.

index.js:

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');


var TestGenerator = module.exports = function TestGenerator(args, options, config) {
  yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

  this.on('end', function () {
    this.installDependencies({ skipInstall: options['skip-install'] });
  });

  this.pkg = JSON.parse(this.readFileAsString(path.join(__dirname, '../package.json')));
};

util.inherits(TestGenerator, yeoman.generators.Base);

TestGenerator.prototype.askFor = function askFor() {
  var cb = this.async();

  // have Yeoman greet the user.
  console.log(this.yeoman);

  var prompts = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'projectName',
    message: 'What would you like to name this project?'
  }];

  this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.projectName = props.projectName;

    cb();
  }.bind(this));
};

TestGenerator.prototype.projectfiles = function projectfiles() {
  this.template('Gruntfile.js');
  this.copy('_package.json', 'package.json');
  this.copy('_bower.json', 'bower.json');
  this.copy('bowerrc', '.bowerrc');
  this.copy('jshintrc', '.jshintrc');
  this.copy('editorconfig', '.editorconfig');
};

TestGenerator.prototype.writeIndex = function writeIndex() {
  this.indexFile = this.readFileAsString(path.join(this.sourceRoot(), 'index.slim'));
  this.indexFile = this.engine(this.indexFile, this);

  this.indexFile = this.appendFiles({
    html: this.indexFile,
    fileType: 'js',
    optimizedPath: 'scripts/main.js',
    sourceFileList: ['scripts/main.js'],
    searchPath: '{app,.tmp}'
  });
};

TestGenerator.prototype.app = function app() {
  this.mkdir('app');
  this.mkdir('app/styles');
  this.mkdir('app/scripts');
  this.mkdir('app/images');

  this.copy('main.scss', 'app/styles/main.scss');
  this.copy('main.js', 'app/scripts/main.js');
  // this.copy('test.slim', 'app/test.slim');

  this.write('app/index.html', this.indexFile);
};
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
// Generated on <%= (new Date).toISOString().split('T')[0] %> using <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %>
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: {
            // Configurable paths
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        'bower-install': {
            app: {
                html: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
                ignorePath: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,webp}',
                        '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%%= yeoman.dist %>']
            },
            html: ['<%%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
        // reference in your app
        modernizr: {
            devFile: '<%%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            files: [
                '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '!<%%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
            ],
            uglify: true
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [ 
                'compass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        slim: { 
      dist: { 
                 options: {
                    pretty: true
                },
        files: { 
          'app/test.html': 'app/templates/test.slim'
        }
      }
    }
    });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-slim');

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'slim',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');

        if (target) {
            grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
        }
        else {
            grunt.task.run(['serve']);
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer',
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'slim',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'copy:dist',
        'modernizr',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

index.slim:

```
DOCTYPE html
html
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"
    title <%= _.capitalize(projectName) %>

    link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bower-foundation/css/normalize.css"
    link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bower-foundation/css/foundation.css"
    // build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css 
    link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"
    // endbuild
    script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"

  body
    div.container Hello
    div#abc
      p there

    // build:js scripts/vendor.js
    // bower:js
    script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"
    // endbower
    // endbuild
```

_package.json:

```
{
  "name": "<%= _.slugify(projectName) %>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.0",
      "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.0",
      "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
      "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
      "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
      "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
      "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
      "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
      "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
      "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.5.0",
      "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
      "grunt-modernizr": "~0.4.0",
      "grunt-newer": "~0.6.0",
      "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
      "grunt-slim": "~0.1.0",
      "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.0",
      "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
      "time-grunt": "~0.2.0",
      "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

_bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "<%= _.slugify(projectName) %>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower-foundation": ">= 4.0.0",
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am at about the same place you are, except that I've been working with Jade instead of Slim. My approach has been to step away from Yeoman for a bit and just start by creating a Gruntfile that will do what I want. Once that is in place, getting things working as a Yeoman generator is pretty straightforward.

Try this if you like:

The grunt-slim task depends on ruby and the slim gem. So first, make sure you have ruby installed (type `ruby -v` in the terminal) and then install the slim gem (enter `gem install slim` in the terminal.)

To work with Grunt you need to create 2 files at the root of your project's directory - a 'package.json' file to store metadata about the project and a 'Gruntfile.js' that is used to load Grunt plugins and configure tasks.

The 'package.json' file is easy - enter `npm init` in the terminal and answer the questions that come up. To install Grunt plugins and have them entered into your 'package.json' file enter `npm install <package name> --save-dev` into the terminal.

So to create a basic 'package.json' file for a test project enter:

```
npm init
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-slim --save-dev
```

Then you need to create a Gruntfile.js. Here is the most basic one possible that will just compile an 'index.slim' file to 'index.html'.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // configure the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
    slim: {  // the task name
      dist: {  // a specific target for the task - it could be called anything
        files: {
          'index.html': 'index.slim' // a dictionary that maps 'destination': 'source'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-slim');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['slim']);
}
```

Now try creating an 'index.slim' file at the root of your project and enter the command `grunt` in the terminal... it should compile to html.

There's some good information about working with files (so you can do more complex things than what I've done) on the Grunt website:
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files

Here's a clear tutorial about writing a build script with Grunt:
http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-awesome-build-script-grunt/

I hope that helps. If you're interested in a Yeoman Jade generator there is one on the Yeoman Community generator site that works very well.

edit ----
I wrote this under the assumption that the Grunt command line interface was installed. It is installed as a component of Yeoman or separately with the commend `npm install -g grunt-cli`